# Android auto authentication mechanism

Tags: android, security

I'm developing an app which will connect to server webservice and exchange data. I want to include auto authentication mechanism in application. I'm not really good at security stuff, so I would like to ask you, how to do it properly. I think, that storing users password in sharedpreferences or database and comparing it with password stored in server is not a good idea, even in encrypted form. I guess that there is some better way to do it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the service will return a key of some sort (typically in a cookie), and you pass that key with each subsequent request.  The server is responsible for keeping track of who has what key.  And of course the key is very large so its unguessable.

On the server side, never store the password.  You store a hash of the password, and when an incoming password comes from a login request, you hash it and compare the hashes.  Better yet you should salt your hashes as well.  If you aren't familiar with security I'd really suggest you use an existing library rather than writing your own.

Comment: OK, so let me understand it step by step. Firstable, I log on via mobile app. Hashes are compared on the server and a key is returned on success. Now I have to store that key in app's shared preferences to use it with each subsequent request?